# Interpret error measure in training sets

Tags: r, forecasting

New in R, using `auto.arima` function for forecasting. 
Here's the sample forecast I worked with

```
    ARIMA(2,0,0)(1,0,0)[12] with non-zero mean 

    Coefficients:
            ar1      ar2    sar1  intercept
         0.8301  -0.2038  0.5245  1785.9265
   s.e.  0.1266   0.1252  0.1408   432.6884

   sigma^2 estimated as 561542:  log likelihood=-482.52
   AIC=975.03   AICc=976.14   BIC=985.5

    Error measures:
                ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE    MAPE      MASE
Training set -2.72559 723.9513 437.8526 -12.09308 27.3989 0.5513069
```

My questions are: How can I tell if the error measures are correct and what are the criteria on how to make a great forecast.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to answer your first question - it depends what you mean by correct. If you need to see the actual equations, you'd need to look at the source code of the package and find the code that computes the calculation. But seeing as how many thousands of people use the forecast package daily, it's safe to assume they're being calculated correct.

If you meant "is this a good ARIMA model", you should take a look at the ACF plots of the residuals and look to see if any of the autocorrelations are above the threshold limits (indicating there is additional modeling to be had). Additionally, you can look at the results of a portmanteau test and if the p-value is high, it's likely your residuals are white noise and you likely have a good ARIMA model for your data.

If your residuals are not white noise, I recommend turning off the stepwise and approximation functions in the auto.arima() function. This will review almost every possible ARIMA model (some restrictions) and find the lowest AIC model. These two parameters are set to TRUE to speed up the algorithm by default.

"A great forecast" is a bit vague and depends on your criteria. You'll need to narrow down what you mean. I recommend the books below (no affiliation) for learning more about forecasting and you can review the ARIMA diagnositics sections as well.

https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series/latest/a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.pdf